# Выбор макcимума из четырех столбцов

Tags: sql, oracle

Во время смерживания двух таблиц, хочу выбрать максимум из 4 столбцов

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_1 T1
  USING TABLE_2 T2
  ON T1.KEY_ID = T2.KEY_ID
WHEN MATCHED
  THEN UPDATE SET T1.VALUE = MAX(T2.VALUE_1, T2.VALUE_2, T2.VALUE_3, T2.VALUE_4)
```

Но в таком виде MAX работать не будет. В каком виде это разместить корректнее?

Comment: т.е. вам нужен максимум из 4х полей одной строки, а не из 4х строк ? на этот случай есть функция greatest. только NULL ей не передавайте

Comment: Спасибо, Mike. Жаль придется NULL'ы отсекать через NVL. Громоздко, но лучше чем ничего. Хоть один столбец точно положительным будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_1 T
USING TABLE_2 t1
ON (T.KEY_ID = t1.KEY_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET T.VALUE_1 = GREATEST(NVL(T1.VALUE_1, 0), NVL(T1.VALUE_2, 0), NVL(T1.VALUE_3, 0), NVL(T1.VALUE_4, 0));
```

Comment: Да, именно так и сделал после коммента Mike'а, спасибо.